# How to distinguish function paramaters from the script arguments in a /bin/sh script?

Tags: shell, arguments, command-line-arguments, sh

Apparently you can access the **arguments** of a `shell script` via $1, $2, etc.

But if you do a function inside the script, you access the **parameters** to a `function` in the same way.

How to do it if I want to create a shell script which receives an argument, and which also has functions that receives parameters?

I've tried doing it but the scope breaks, the function thinks there are no parameters if I pass no arguments to the script :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found this to be the case, the function parameters have different scope than the script parameters

```sh
bar ()
{
  echo $1
}
echo $1
bar bird
```

Output

```
$ foo.sh

bird

$ foo.sh dog
dog
bird
```

Comment: so weird! in my first testing it didn't work... I'll try to find the culprit, thanks!